# Dropdownlist keeps choosing the first value and showing all the data from database, not showing the selected value

Tags: c#, asp.net

Drop down list keeps choosing the first value and showing all the data from database, not showing the selected value. I want to make to show only the selected truckplateno to show on the gridview. Now I am having a problem that the dropdownlist keeps selecting on the first value on the list and further more it shows all the data from this table on the gridview which I intend to show only the selected one

```
public partial class Search_Engine : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    #region Database

    static string HostName = "localhost";
    static string DatabaseName = "finalproject";
    static string TableName = "truckinfo";
    //static string TableBucket = "bucketbrigade";
    static string UserName = "root";
    static string Password = "";

    //--- Used for access to database infomation-----
    string ConnStr = "Data Source=" + HostName + ";" +
                     "Database=" + DatabaseName + ";" +
                     "User ID=" + UserName + ";" +
                     "Password=" + Password;

    string Qry = "";

    MySqlConnection Con;
    MySqlCommand Cmd;
    MySqlDataReader Rdr;

    #endregion
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {

            BindData();

        }
        using (Con = new MySqlConnection(ConnStr))
        {
            Con.Open();
            using (Cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM truckinfo", Con))
            {

                using (Rdr = Cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (Rdr.HasRows)
                    {
                        DropDownList1.DataSource = Rdr;
                        DropDownList1.DataValueField = "truckplateno";
                        DropDownList1.DataTextField =  "truckplateno";
                        DropDownList1.DataBind();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private void BindData()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            MySqlConnection Con = new MySqlConnection(ConnStr);
            Con.Open();
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " +
                              DatabaseName + "." + TableName, Con);

            da.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }

            Con.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.ToString());
        }
    }



    protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {




    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Con = new MySqlConnection(ConnStr);
        Con.Open();
        try
        {
            String getquery;
           // String a;
            getquery = DropDownList1.Text;
            TextBox1.Text = getquery;
           // a = TextBox2.Text;
          //  TextBox1.Text = a;
            Qry = @"SELECT * FROM finalproject.truckinfo WHERE truckplateno=" + "'" + getquery + "'" + ";";
            Cmd = new MySqlCommand(Qry, Con);
            Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Con.Close();
            BindData();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
    protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you intending to have if (!IsPostBack)? The ! is pretty important there.

Comment: Yes, but I dont want it to show before selecting the droplistvalue

Comment: with if (IsPostBack) you load the page and the dropdown on every postback

Comment: So what happens if you place the BindData(); in the DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged ? then it will only load it after you selected a value in the dropdown

Comment: After correcting it, how to show only the selected value on grid view?

Comment: thry this     MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " +
                              DatabaseName + "." + TableName Where truckplateno=@Partruckplateno , Con); under it you to cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Partruckplateno", DropDownList1.SelectedItem.text);

Comment: in between the TableName, it doesnt allow me to use Where.

Comment: Sorry no time to test it but what if you put brackets around the where

Comment: MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " +
                              DatabaseName + "." + TableName + "Where truckplateno=@truckplateno", Con);
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@truckplateno", DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text);                                                                               if I do like this, it gives me an error System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at

Answer (score 0):

Use `!IsPostBack` and include the code that binds the `DropDownList`:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindData();

        using (Con = new MySqlConnection(ConnStr))
        {
            Con.Open();
            using (Cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM truckinfo", Con))
            {

                using (Rdr = Cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (Rdr.HasRows)
                    {
                        DropDownList1.DataSource = Rdr;
                        DropDownList1.DataValueField = "truckplateno";
                        DropDownList1.DataTextField =  "truckplateno";
                        DropDownList1.DataBind();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise events aren't triggered since you always load the original database values.